# use pygtk for android apps development

Tags: java, android, python, pygtk, kivy

I want to use pygtk app for android app development. I want to use app like pygtk which will have easy drag and drop options for developing the front end for android application.

Is there any of such thing which can let me design my front end for android app with drag and drop? (specially in python or else in java)

Comment: Have you ever found anything for getting gtk on Android?

Answer (score 2):

I see you tagged the question with `kivy`, I can only answer that we don't have such a thing for kivy yet, although a GSOC student got accepted for this and will start working on it soon, let's hope it'll work out nicely :). I'm of the opinion that the kvlang we have in kivy makes the need of a Graphical Designer far less than in other toolkits, but i guess YMMMV.

Other than that, I don't think you can do PyGTK development on Android currently, but I think PySide works, so maybe QtDesigner or some other Qt design application would be worth a look?

Comment: Has anything changed regarding kivy?

Comment: yes, there is kivy-designer now, but it certainly needs more love.